# Problems with the alpha in Navigation Bar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, alpha, uicolor, ios7.1

I have one problem. In iOS 7.0 my Navigation Bar app shown like these:

[image]

But in iOS 7.1 shown like these:

[image]

Somone knows why??

The color is:

[UIColor  colorWithRed:(62/255.0) green:(154/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:(200/255.0)]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with my toolbar color. Does setting the alpha value change anything.